# Issue with Converting XML file into single String

Tags: java, android, xml, stringbuilder

I am creating an XML file from my Database and storing it in Internal storage. I require data from XML file into a single string. For which, i am using the following method.

```
   BufferedReader br;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(pathDAR)));
                String line;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line.trim());
                    String temp = sb.toString().substring(38);

                    Log.v("XML TO String", "" + temp);
                    Log.v("Lengths : ", "" + temp.length() + " " + sb.length());

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I have been getting string in the Log, but it seems to be stopping abruptly in the middle.
For e.g. I am supposed to get records string like this. Beginning and ending with database tag.

```
<database name="DAR.db"><table name="DARWorkDetails"><row><col name="id">1</col><col name="date">05-28-2013</col><col name="visited_city_ID">1264</col><col name="employee_ID">107</col><col name="work_type_ID">1</col><col name="name">null</col><col name="customer_Id">null</col><col name="customer_type_ID">null</col><col name="sub_customer_id">null</col><col name="reason_ID">14</col><col name="reason">ABM SM MEETING</col><col name="remarks">gfhii</col><col name="work_with">211,162</col><col name="IsCustomer">N</col><col name="created_by">107</col><col name="position_id">72</col><col name="designation_Id">3</col><col name="submit_date">05-28-2013</col><col name="IsFinal">null</col></row></table></database>
```

Instead i have been getting string like this :

```
<database name="DAR.db"><table name="DARWorkDetails"><row><col name="id">1</col><col name="date">05-28-2013</col><col name="visited_city_ID">1264</col><col name="employee_ID">107</col><col name="work_type_ID">1</col><col name="name">null</col><col name="customer_Id">null</col><col name="customer_type_ID">null</col><col name="sub_customer_id">null</col><col name="reason_ID">14</col><col name="reason">ABM SM MEETING</col><col name="remarks">gfhii</col><col name="work_with">211,162</col><col name="IsCustomer">N</col><col name="created_by">107</col><col name="position_id">72</col><col name="designation_Id">3</col><col name="submit_date">05-28-2013</col><col name="IsFinal">null</co
```

The String is stopping in the middle. For the sake of example i have only put small example string above. In reality my database has multiple records and i have counted length of the string to around 15640, before abrupt end of the string.

Are there any limitations with StringBuilder in regards to storing characters? I suppose there is memory issue since i have been able to get string fully for records fewer than 10. Problem seems to be arising when records go into upwards of 10. Any help in understanding of solving this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check

It may happen your output is perfect but your `Log cat` is not displaying it whole.

```
Log.v("XML TO String", "" + temp);
Log.v("Lengths : ", "" + temp.length() + " " + sb.length());
```

See [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580062/string-is-being-truncated-when-its-too-long)

Comment: Ok will check and let you know.

Comment: You saved my day. Much appreciate you help buddy. Marked as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I created this class to read strings from a xml file saved in internal storage device, it returns a list , if you want the whole extended string you only need concatenate to link together, if doesn't found the file return an empty list this is all you need to read XML files and parse to Strings, I hope to help!

```
public class readXMLFile {
private String filePath = "FileStorage";
private String fileName = "File.xml";
private final String tag = "Internal Read Persistence";
File internalFileData;

public readXMLFile() {// default constructor
}

public File getXMLFile(Context context){
File directory = null;
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
directory = cw.getDir(filePath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
internalFileData = new File(directory, fileName);
if(internalFileData.exists()){
Log.i("ReadXMLFile","File returned");
return internalFileData;
}
else{
Log.i(tag,"the file doesn't exists!");
return null;
}
}

public List<String> readFile(Context context) {
List<String> l = new LinkedList<String>();
try {
File directory = null;
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
directory = cw.getDir(filePath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
internalFileData = new File(directory, fileName);

if (internalFileData.exists()) {
Log.i("Internal Data", "the root exists!!");
try {
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(internalFileData);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
l.add(line);
}
try {
if (in != null) {
in.close();
}
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.i(tag, "Exception closing persistence connection");
                }
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.wtf("Fatal Exception", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
} else {
Log.i(tag, "File doesn't exists");
return l;//return empty list
}
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.wtf(tag, "Exception DATA READING: " + e.getMessage());
return l;
}
Log.i(tag, "file found return");
return l;
}

}
```