# Android Http Response is incomplete. Returns an unterminated json object

Tags: android, json, http-post

I am using `HttpClient` 4.3.6 to perform http GET and POST requests. Right now I am using multipartentity to send a few string parameters and an image in the form of a file. I am able to successfully post the data but my problem comes in when I get the HTTP response. The response contains json data.

What happens is the HTTP response is incomplete and when i try to create a json object with the data i get jsonexception error saying:

> Unterminated object at character 407.

I noticed that the response does not contain closed braces. Is this a problem on android or should I check the server? Because I am able to see the data properly on postman and on ios. I have never faced this issue before and don't know how to solve this.

This is my code to post and get the response:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        String url = params[0];
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(imageBytes, "image.jpg");
        entity.addPart("image_data", bab);
        entity.addPart("action", new StringBody("1", "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        entity.addPart("name", new StringBody("asdfg", "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        entity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody("157", "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        entity.addPart("birthday", new StringBody("18-04-1995", "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        entity.addPart("gender", new StringBody("male", "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        entity.addPart("is_jlpt_student", new StringBody(String.valueOf(0), "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        entity.addPart("relationship", new StringBody("Father", "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        entity.addPart("relationship_id", new StringBody(String.valueOf(10002), "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        entity.addPart("is_creator", new StringBody(String.valueOf(1), "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        entity.addPart("email", new StringBody(email, "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        httppost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String response = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
        Log.i("HttpResponse", response);

        return response;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute (String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject json_data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
        String json_userid = json_data.getString("user_id");
        String json_username = json_data.getString("name");
        String json_email = json_data.getString("email");
        String json_country = json_data.getString("country_code");
        String json_imagefilename = json_data.getString("image_filename");
        String json_imgurl = json_data.getString("image_url");

        Toast.makeText(ParentGuardianProfile.this, "ImageFile " + json_imagefilename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


       User new_user = userdao.createUser(json_userid, json_username, json_email,json_imagefilename,json_country,selectedImageUri.toString(), 1);


       Log.i("SQLITE", "added user : " + new_user.getmUserName() + new_user.getmId());


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And my json response is :

```
{"status":1,"message":"success","data":{"child_id":"381","name":"asdfg","image_filename":"C201603021734476.jpg","image_url":"https:\/\/innokid.blob.core.windows.net\/media\/child\/381.jpg","birthday":"18-04-1995","gender":"male","is_jltp_student":"0","relationship":"Father","relationship_id":"10002","is_creator":1,"rank":1,"qrcode_url":"http:\/\/innokid.azurewebsites.net\/uploads\/qrcode\/child_381.png"
```

I tried using String buffer as suggested in this post [String is being truncated when its too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580062/string-is-being-truncated-when-its-too-long) . But i still get the same result.

Comment: is it your full json response?

Comment: please check the server code either its encoding to json properly

Answer (score 0):

Code looks ok at first glance.
How do you got know that the json data is cut? Logcat can truncate text. Debugger should be more reliable in this case.

Try to generate this same request with some tools like curl / SoapUI and validate JSON you got with some formatter / validator (you'll easily find a few of such tools).

It's beyond the range of question, but using raw Android built-in communication libraries seems to be a little bit masochistic. Have you ever consider to use Retrofit?

Comment: I checked the response string in the debugger. It did not have the closing braces of the jsonObject

Comment: So my advice is to check what server is returning with some independent tool

Comment: i checked on Postman and the response appears properly.No character is missed

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is problematic `String response = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());`

may be you should use some other function to convert response toString...

Apparently the json is missing two curly brackets '}}' at the end, which can happen due to some bug in the toString code.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled up an old project that was using the `org.apache.http` stuff and below is how I was parsing the response.  As you can see it is rather cumbersome.  There are many tested and maintained libraries out there that are better suited to this kind of heavy-lifting.

```java
// Get hold of the response entity (-> the data):
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null) {
    // Read the content stream
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
    if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
        instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
    }

    // Convert content stream to a String
    resultString = convertStreamToString(instream);
    instream.close();

    // Do stuff with resultString here

    // Consume Content
    entity.consumeContent();

}
```

And the `convertStreamToString()` method:

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
         * BufferedReader.readLine() method. We iterate until the BufferedReader
         * return null which means there's no more data to read. Each line will
         * appended to a StringBuilder and returned as String.
         * 
         * (c) public domain:
         * http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/
         * 11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/
         */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 8192);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this issue by replacing httpclient library with Android Asynchronous Http Client. Now it works fine. Thanks a lot for your help!
However, I still dont understand why the response was truncated when i used httpclient.